# I get an 415 error message when I add to request DTO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, postman

I have a controller:

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void postForm(@RequestPart("payload") MyDto dto,
                                       @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {

}
```

When I send a post request from Postman, I get an 415 error.
[image]

but when I try using the controller only without the DTO, everything works fine.

Comment: I think that what you're missing here is the MediaType for a JSON format. Use either MediaType.ALL or add one MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON for *consumes* attribute.

Comment: @SebastianI. with MediaType.ALL i have the same error and with APPLICATION_JSON i have an 405 error

Answer (score 1):

2 options :

1) Save your json payload in a json file(.json) and send it via postman as a file instead of plain text.

2) add content-type tab via "show more actions" (...) and choose content-type.

[image]